# XRM JavaScript : Enable/ and Disable user

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have tried to make Enable/Disable user with clear term date in systemuser entity form  by using Javascript and written below code.

```
var ClearTermDate= function () {
        var termDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_termdate");
        if (termDate!= null) {
            termDate.setValue(null);
        }
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("isdisabled").setValue(false);
        Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
    };
```

`isdisabled` attribute is not updating. Please suggest code or alternative solution.

Comment: User entity? CRM Version and deployment?

Comment: Systemuser Entity and CRM 2015

Comment: Please check this sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602914(v=crm.7).aspx

Comment: It is C# code , need to do in javascript

Comment: can you setup a pre-update plugin on systemuser entity & check the targetentity for "isdisabled" attribute, I guess system may strip this attribute..? on premise or IFD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bingo! `isdisabled` is Read-only property in systemuser entity per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608065.aspx#Properties). You cannot do this in JS directly like you're doing.

You have to follow one of these:

1. If you are in 2015 - use [soap call](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/07/set-status-or-state-of-record-using.html) to do `SetStateRequest` in JS
2. If you have 2015 update 1 - use web api to do `SetStateRequest` in JS
3. Or setup a plugin on update of Term date to [disable user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602914(v=crm.7).aspx)